# How to create a device driver installation dialog with a device name using CMD?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, driver, rundll32

I want to create a driver installation balloon (i.e that says "Installing Device Driver software", but if I use this command:

```
rundll32 pnpui.dll,SimplifiedDINotification
```

It creates like this:
[Device Driver Installation Dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7XbZt.gif)
But I want to create a driver installation dialog, when finished, writes the names of drivers that is currently installing, and also it would be useful to give me a way to install a couple of drivers in a single notification.

I have tried:

- Giving a param to RUNDLL32.EXE while creating the balloon.
- Giving a .inf file to RUNDLL32.EXE while creating the balloon.

I have expected:

- Driver Installation

I have got:

- Driver Installation balloon that doesn't show names of drivers.

Note: A device driver software with a name is like this:
[A device driver software with a name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uEIFb.jpg)

Comment: That looks like Vista, why so old?

Comment: This is NOT Vista, because of Aero taskbar look. (This is Windows 7 Build 7601 a.k.a Windows NT 6.1.7601)

Comment: My apologies.  Same question though.